# Returning the lat long with minimum distance in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to find the lat, long combination with minimum distance. x_lat, x_long are constant. I want to get combinations of y_latitude, y_longitude and calculate the distance and find out the minimum distance and return the corresponding y_latitude, y_longitude.

The following is trying,

```
x_lat = 33.50194395
x_long = -112.048885

y_latitude = ['56.16', '33.211045400000003', '37.36']
y_longitude = ['-117.3700631', '-118.244']
```

I have a distance function which would return the distance,

```
from math import radians, cos, sin, asin, sqrt
def distance(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    """
    Calculate the great circle distance between two points 
    on the earth (specified in decimal degrees)
    """
    # convert decimal degrees to radians 
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    # haversine formula 
    dlon = lon2 - lon1 
    dlat = lat2 - lat1 
    a = sin(dlat/2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon/2)**2
    c = 2 * asin(sqrt(a)) 
    km = 6367 * c
    return km
```

So I tried something like the following,

```
dist = []
for i in itertools.product(y_latitude , y_longitude):
    print i
    dist.append(distance(float(i[1]),float(i[0]),float(x_long), float(x_lat)))

print dist.index(min(dist))
```

So this creates all possible combinations of y_latitude and y_longitude and calculates distance and returns the index of minimum distance. I am not able to make it return the corresponding y_latitude and y_longitude.

Here the index of minimum distance is 2 and output is 2. The required output is ('33.211045400000003', '-117.3700631'), which I am not able to make it return.

Can anybody help me in solving the last piece?

Thanks

Comment: return `min(dist)` instead return its index

Comment: That would just return the minimum distance. I want the corresponding y_lat and y_long of the minimum distance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
dist = []
for i in itertools.product(y_latitude , y_longitude):
    dist.append([distance(float(i[1]),float(i[0]),float(x_long), float(x_lat)),i])
min_lat,min_lng = min(dist, key = lambda x: x[0])[1]
```

Append the lat and long  along with the dist, And get `min` of first index,